# C# regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have string like this:

```
{F971h}[0]<0>some result code: 1
```

and I want to split it into:

- F971
- 0
- 0
- some result code: 1

I know I can first split `"{|}|[|]|<|>`" it into:

- {F971h}
- [0]
- <0>
- some result code: 1

and next: {F971h} -> F971; [0] -> 0; etc.

But how can I do it with one regular expression?
I try somethink like this:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?<timestamp>[0-9A-F]+)" + @"(?<subsystem>\d+)" + @"(?<level>\d+)" + @"(?<messagep>[0-9A-Za-z]+)");
var result = rgx.Matches(input);
```

Comment: As the internet has many examples of how to use regex, what did you try with regex so far? show some code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: Try [`^{([^{}]*)}\[([^][]*)]<([^<>]*)>(.*)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%7b(%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d*)%7d%5c%5b(%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d*)%5d%3c(%5b%5e%3c%3e%5d*)%3e(.*)&i=%7bF971h%7d%5b0%5d%3c0%3esome+result+code%3a+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your regex:

- You do not allow lowercase ASCII letters in the first capture group (add `a-z` or a `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` flag)
- The delimiting characters are missing in the pattern (`<`, `>`, `[`, `]`, etc.)

Use

```
{(?<timestamp>[0-9a-zA-F]+)}\[(?<subsystem>\d+)]<(?<level>\d+)>(?<messagep>.+)
^                 ^^^      ^^^                 ^^             ^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%7B(%3F%3Ctimestamp%3E%5B0-9a-zA-F%5D%2B)%7D%5C%5B(%3F%3Csubsystem%3E%5Cd%2B)%5D%3C(%3F%3Clevel%3E%5Cd%2B)%3E(%3F%3Cmessagep%3E.%2B)&i=%7BF971h%7D%5B0%5D%3C0%3Esome%20result%20code%3A%201)

Since the `messagep` group should match just the rest of the line, I suggest just using `.+` at the end. Else, you'd need to replace your `[0-9A-Za-z]+` that does not allow whitespace with something like `[\w\s]+` (match all word chars and whitespaces, 1 or more times).

[image]

[C# code](http://ideone.com/5jxwc7):

```
var s = @"{F971h}[0]<0>some result code: 1";
var pat = @"{(?<timestamp>[0-9a-zA-F]+)}\[(?<subsystem>\d+)]<(?<level>\d+)>(?<messagep>.+)";
var m = Regex.Match(s, pat);
if (m.Success)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(m.Groups["timestamp"].Value);
    Console.Out.WriteLine(m.Groups["subsystem"].Value);
    Console.Out.WriteLine(m.Groups["level"].Value);
    Console.Out.WriteLine(m.Groups["messagep"].Value);
}
```

Or for a multiline string containing multiple matches:

```
var s = "{F971h}[0]<0>some result code: 1\r\n{FA71h}[0]<0>some result code: 3\r\n{FB72h}[0]<0>some result code: 5";
var pat = @"{(?<timestamp>[0-9a-zA-F]+)}\[(?<subsystem>\d+)]<(?<level>\d+)>(?<messagep>[^\r\n]+)";
var res = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(s, pat)
     .Cast<System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match>()
     .Select(x => new[] { 
            x.Groups["timestamp"].Value, 
            x.Groups["subsystem"].Value,
            x.Groups["level"].Value,
            x.Groups["messagep"].Value})
      .ToList();
```

[image]

Comment: You cactually need to use `(?<messagep>[^\r\n]+)` inside a multiline strings in order not to capture a `\r`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try just `Split` without any regular expressions:

```
string source = "{F971h}[0]<0>some result code: 1";

string[] items = source.Split(new char[] { '{', '}', '[', ']', '<', '>' },
  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Test:

```
// F971h
// 0
// 0
// some result code: 1
Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, items));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it like that:

```
string line = @"{F971h}[0]<0>some result code: 1";

var matchCollection = Regex.Matches(line, @"\{(?<timestamp>.*?)\}\[(?<subsystem>.*?)\]<(?<level>.*?)>(?<messagep>.*)");
if (matchCollection.Count > 0)
{
    string timestamp = matchCollection[0].Groups["timestamp"].Value;
    string subsystem = matchCollection[0].Groups["subsystem"].Value;
    string level = matchCollection[0].Groups["level"].Value;
    string messagep = matchCollection[0].Groups["messagep"].Value;
    Console.Out.WriteLine("First part is {0}, second: {1}, thrid: {2}, last: {3}", timestamp, subsystem, level, messagep);
}
else
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine("No match found.");
}
```

You can watch it live [here on regex storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%7B(%3F%3Cnumber%3E.*%3F)%5C%7D%5C%5B(%3F%3Carray%3E.*%3F)%5C%5D%3C(%3F%3Cvalue%3E.*%3F)%3E(%3F%3Ctext%3E.*)&i=%7BF971h%7D%5B0%5D%3C0%3Esome%20result%20code%3A%201). You'll have to learn about:

- [Named capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html)
- [Repetitions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Comment: Actually, OP pattern contains named capture groups and quantifiers. Also, there is no need escaping `]`, `{` and `}` here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it wasn't included in the first version I've worked with, I'm re-reading it. Thanks for the notice

Comment: Thank you for answer but when I try your code I got matchCollection.Count equals 1 and Value is the same like input (string line)

Comment: @Genzi of which `Value` are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! Code below works for me. I missed that it can be multiple string:

```
{F971h}[0]<0>some result code: 1\r\n{FA71h}[0]<0>some result code: 3\r\n{FB72h}[0]<0>some result code: 5
```

code:

```
        var pat = @"{(?<timestamp>[0-9a-zA-F]+)}\[(?<subsystem>\d+)]<(?<level>\d+)>(?<message>.+)";
        var collection = Regex.Matches(input, pat);

        foreach (Match m in collection)
        {
            var timestamp = m.Groups["timestamp"];
            var subsystem = m.Groups["subsystem"];
            var level = m.Groups["level"];
            var message = m.Groups["message"];
        }
```

Comment: Please check my updated answer for a multiple match option. If you do not need a linebreak in the message part, you cannot use `.` since it matches `\r`.